# DLL of entity framework not work

Tags: entity-framework, dll

In my project i use in dll of project in entity framework that I build, I have for example class like this:

```
public class Games
{
    public int GameID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public float Time { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }

    //Collection of all the players that play in the game
    public virtual ICollection<PlayerGame> PlayersInGame { get; set; }

}
```

in class player game define property of games like this:

```
    public virtual  Games Game { get; set; }
```

The constrains define on model building.

Game in player game is foreign key in tables.

when i test it on this project the collection fill details.

but when i used the dll in other project the collection empty.

the code in other project is like this:

```
GamesContext MyContext = new GamesContext();
List<Games> GamesList= MyContext.GamesTbl.ToList();
```

in the context class i have the tables and the constrains and it work in the project of the entity frameWork!

Comment: Can you show the code that you're using against this DLL?

Comment: So in the other projects you're using this library in, are configuring the database access correctly?

Comment: Thank you. And are you adding values to the `Games`, before you add `Games` to the `GamesList`?

Comment: I copy the config file from the entity framework project to config file in my project (WCF)

Comment: Yes i have values in the DB i check it in the entity project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DLL eventually did work ..

There were problems in the config file